# git - messed up with submodule

Tags: git, svn

I have 2 individual git repositories, for instance, like this:

1) MyApplication (V1)

2) MyLibrary (V1)

I added 'MyLibrary' as a submodule to 'MyApplication', then made some changes to 'MyLibrary' at the submodule's source files, and then I committed and pushed the changes.

What happen now is that the latest change of 'MyLibrary' is a commit of 'MyApplication', its no longer going back to the orginial 'MyLibrary'

So my current repositories look like this:

1) MyApplication (V1)

1.1) --> Submodule MyLibrary (V2)

2) MyLibrary (V1)

With Subversion, when you commit any externals, the change always go back to the original repository

The concept of submodule in git really confused me a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Look at submodules in Git as separate repositories. What you need to do is treat them like separate repositories meaning if you make a change on the submodule (in this case MyLibrary) you would also need to commit and push that submodule to remote separately.

They are pretty much independent from each other when it comes to changes within the submodule. "MyLibrary" only says: "Hey, I have dependencies on this submodule, also keep that one updated when fetching".

Comment: Is it normal that a submodule folder does not contains a .git folder but a .git file instead?  Cause that's what I got.

Comment: Have never thought of that but looking into my setup I do have .git file rather than .git folder in submodules. So that seems correct. I can't give you a proper answer why that is though.